# TextBox TextChanged Event firing when ImageButton pressed

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I have a complete grid view with up to 12 rows of data at a time. The first column has 3 ImageButtons (Comment, Attach, Logs) which bring popups onto the screen to allow the user to further interact. The fourth column has a textbox(txtValue) that allows the user to insert a value for that row. when that happens the txtValue_TextChanged event is fired and the value is saved to an object amongst other values and then saved to the database.

[Image Showing Grid Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N69Ek.png)

The issue I'm having is that when first navigating to the page and clicking on any of the three ImageButtons it fires Page_Load which is expected however instead of firing the respective buttons event it fires the txtValue_TextChanged event first for every row in the grid (Which causes an error notification as it should), then it fires the ImageButton event after.

Once this issue has happened once it doesn't happen again unless the user navigates away from the page and returns.

I have an object list stored in viewstate with all the objects within the grid for them to be visible at all times.

I have seen a few solutions that recomend checking for Postback first, I have included such in the page load followed by populating dropdown lists, comboboxes, then i populate the entry list in viewstate and then bind the grid from said entry list.

Any suggestions as to why the txtValue_TextChanged is firing for every row when its not supposed to be?